# Reset the game screen when a particular score is reached

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a simple game using kivy.The game is like this--

-There are 9 buttons and a scoreboard covering the screen.Out of the 9 buttons,3 of them are of one color(say red) and the other 6 buttons are of a different color(say green).

-If the player clicks a red button,its color changes to green and the score gets incremented by 1.However, if a green button is clicked,the player scores a negative mark,the color doesn't change this time.

-Once all the buttons are green or the score is a multiple of 3,I want a new screen to be displayed with a different configuration(I  am able to get random configuration of the buttons each time)

-The game will go on for a definite time interval ,say 60s

But I am not able to switch over to the next screen,once all the buttons are green or when the score is a multiple of 3,i.e. the third step.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you are not able to switch screens?

Comment: I have just started using kivy.So,I do not know how to get the next screen.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]. It's hard to answer your question otherwise